# Error in python 3.5: can't add `map` results together

Tags: python-3.x

I have piece of code using python 2.7 and i am trying to convert it so that i can use it with python 3.5 but i get an error on the flowing code due to map. what is the best way to resolve this ?

File "/Users/newbie/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/caffe/caffe_utils.py", line 74, in parse_network
    blobs = top_blobs + bottom_blobs

TypeError: **unsupported operand type(s) for +**: '**map**' and '**map**'

```
 def parse_network(layers, phase):
 '''
    Construct a network from the layers by making all blobs and  layers(operations) as nodes.
'''
  nb_layers = len(layers)
  network = {}

   for l in range(nb_layers):
     included = False
     try:
        # try to see if the layer is phase specific
        if layers[l].include[0].phase == phase:
            included = True
     except IndexError:
        included = True

     if included:
        layer_key = 'caffe_layer_' + str(l)  # actual layers, special annotation to mark them
        if layer_key not in network:
            network[layer_key] = []
        top_blobs = map(str, layers[l].top)
        bottom_blobs = map(str, layers[l].bottom)
        blobs = top_blobs + bottom_blobs

        for blob in blobs:
            if blob not in network:
                network[blob] = []
        for blob in bottom_blobs:
            network[blob].append(layer_key)
        for blob in top_blobs:
                network[layer_key].append(blob)
 network = acyclic(network)  # Convert it to be truly acyclic
 network = merge_layer_blob(network)  # eliminate 'blobs', just have layers
 return network
```

Comment: You may also want to consider taking this piece of code to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (once fixed), since those three for-loops right above each other can be simplified a lot. A `network = collections.defaultdict(list)` can get rid of the complete `for blob in blobs` loop, for example.

Answer (score 4):

`map` in Python 3 return an iterator, while `map` in Python 2 returns a list:

Python 2:

```
>>> type(map(abs, [1, -2, 3, -4]))
<type 'list'>
```

Python 3:

```
>>> type(map(abs, [1, -2, 3, -4]))
<class 'map'>
```

(Note that `map` is even a bit more special, but it's certainly not a `list`.)

You can't simply add iterators. But you can chain them, using `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> chain(map(abs, [1, -2, 3, -4]), map(abs, [5, -6, 7, -8]))
<itertools.chain object at 0x7fe0dc0775f8>
```

For the final result, you either have to loop over the chain, or evaluate it:

```
>>> for value in chain(map(abs, [1, -2, 3, -4]), map(abs, [5, -6, 7, -8])):
...     print(value)
... 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

or

```
>>> list(chain(map(abs, [1, -2, 3, -4]), map(abs, [5, -6, 7, -8])))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Note that the former comes more naturally, and evaluating the iterator as the last example should be avoided unless absolutely necessary: it can save memory and possibly computational power (for example, where there is a break in the loop, so that further values do not have to evaluated).